# Pandas DataFrame to Seaborn

Tags: pandas, dataframe, seaborn

I'm attempting to draw seaborn heatmap using pandas DataFrame.
My data format is as below

```
visit_table

   yyyymm  visit_cnt
0  201101      91252
1  201102     140571
2  201103     141457
3  201104     147680
4  201105     154066
...

68  201609     591242
69  201610     650174
70  201611     507579
71  201612     465218
```

How can I change DataFrame to seaborn data format as below

```
  2011       2012     2013   2015

1     91252
2     14057
3     147680
4     154066
...
11    123455
12    1234456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) for converting the column `yyyymm` and then create new `Series` (columns) with [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html) and [`dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.year.html). Last reshape by [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and replace `NaN` to `0` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) if necessary.

```
df['yyyymm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yyyymm'], format='%Y%m')
df1 = pd.pivot(index=df['yyyymm'].dt.month, columns=df['yyyymm'].dt.year, values=df.visit_cnt)
       .fillna(0)
print (df1)
yyyymm      2011      2016
yyyymm                    
1        91252.0       0.0
2       140571.0       0.0
3       141457.0       0.0
4       147680.0       0.0
5       154066.0       0.0
9            0.0  591242.0
10           0.0  650174.0
11           0.0  507579.0
12           0.0  465218.0
```

Another solution is similar, only reshape by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['yyyymm'] = pd.to_datetime(df['yyyymm'], format='%Y%m')
df['year'] = df['yyyymm'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['yyyymm'].dt.month
df1 = df.set_index(['month','year'])['visit_cnt'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
year     2011    2016
month                
1       91252       0
2      140571       0
3      141457       0
4      147680       0
5      154066       0
9           0  591242
10          0  650174
11          0  507579
12          0  465218
```

Finally, use [`seaborn.heatmap`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.heatmap(df1)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: jezrael - Thank you very much

Comment: Glad can help you - small advice to future - Please add some code, what you try to question, then get no downvotes. Nice day.